# "How do you do?"

Tags: expressions, idiom

How to ask "How do you do?" in Latin. 
*Quomodo te habes*, is it common?
What other common greetings for the "How are you?" exist?

I have seen:

- Quomodo es?
- Quid agis?
- Quomodo te habes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not use *quomodo es*.
It is a calque of the English phrase and does not strike me as sensible Latin.
Of course, if someone finds attestations in reliable sources, I am ready to revert my opinion.
Translated another way, *quomodo es?* is "in what way are you?", and that should give a hint at the unnatural nature of the phrase.
Many idioms are unnatural but have become common, but the same turn of phrase is not necessarily sensible in all languages.

If you were to expand the English question "how are you?" to "how are you feeling?", you would get better translations.
For example, *ut vales?* is a good way to ask for health, and it is the classically attested choice.
Mind you that I would take that as an actual question, not a mere greeting.
*Quomodo te habes?* and *quomodo vales?* are essentially synonymous to it but are more recent choices — I am only familiar with them as phrases used in contemporary Latin in Finland, and I claim no classical precedent.
If you want to stick to what the Romans would have said, then *ut vales?* is the way to go.

*Quid agis?* is a good question, but it's more directly "what are you doing?".
I wouldn't use it for "how do you do?" or "how are you?" but "what's up?".

Both *ut vales?* and *quid agis?* are classically attested phrases and therefore your best and safest choices.
Both are found in the play *Persa* by Plautus.

Comment: I think _quid agis?_ is indeed the best match, often used like "what's up?". I would add _ut vales?_ and _ut valetur?_ for the "how are you feeling?" flavour.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Good point! I added *ut vales* as an option. I chose to leave the passive out for simplicity, and I'm sure I've overlooked something else too. There's always room to go beyond basics, but I think an elementary answer is worthwhile at least as one of the answers.

Comment: I wonder about *Valesne?*

Comment: @TimLymingtonsupportsMonica That sounds more like "Are you ok?" to me, not really a greeting.

Comment: *quōmodo valēs* doesn't ask for *"bene"* or *"male"*, but for *"dīs juvantibus"* or *"multā medicīnā"* or *"meīs vīribus"*

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I think it could ask for any of those. I know of no better way to ask in Latin how someone is doing, but I'd be happy to learn if there is one.

Comment: ***ut** valēs?* [is the basic way to ask this](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%23ut+vales), [the other variant](http://www.mlat.uzh.ch/MLS/advsuchergebnis.php?suchbegriff="quomodo%20vales"&table=&level2_name=&from_year=&to_year=&mode=SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2&lang=0&corpus=all&verses=&lemmatised=&suchenin=alle) seems to be post-breakdown of the Classical system of conjunctions, although it might occur around the Classical period in some subliterary texts, because the two conjunctions were already largely interchangeable by that point. Still, set expressions are better left untouched

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Thanks! I didn't know that *ut vales* is indeed the classically attested choice and *quomodo vales* is a more recent variant. A few quick corpus searches indeed verify that. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Related to "How do you do?" is "Pleased to meet you." = "mihi placet" (Glosbe), All the other examples of its use include some qualification; though, the meaning in these becomes "it is pleasing to me". On Q:https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13623/1982, I made the mistake of assuming that "videtur mihi" = "it seems fine to me" can stand alone, without qualification. Vincenzo pointed out it must be followed by an "ut" or "si" clause.  Apart from "Pleased to meet you.", can "mihi placet" stand alone, meaning "it (is pleasing or) seems fine to me" in any circumumstances?

Comment: @tony That's best asked as a separate question. Whether *mihi placet* can stand for "pleased to meet you" is a nuanced matter. Being technically grammatical does not imply being correct or idiomatic. One possibility is to ask how the Romans expressed their pleasure at a new acquaintance. I'd be happy to see that covered on our site!

Comment: @tony I'm 99% positive that "mihi placet" can't be used like that any more than "I like" can in English. The reason it's given as an option on Glosbe is that someone mistranslated it as "encantado/enchanteé", which can be used this way in Portuguese, Spanish and French. Glosbe should not be used as a source or as a learning material. It can be used as a source for some useful suggestions when you can already reliably spot if those are as far off as in this case.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian You could give that as an answer to [Tony's new question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14731/79).

Comment: Unbrutal_Russian: Welcome back. Long time no see? Thank you. This may explain why "mihi placet" does not appear in isolation; at least, not in my searches. Thanks again.

Comment: May I also draw everyone's attention to Eleanor Dickey's book *Learning Latin the Ancient Way: Latin Textbooks from the Ancient World* - a real gem! https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/learning-latin-the-ancient-way/069A72E3A677FDAC79DA1B15E85E8889 You can find lots of useful material there, e.g. "-Quid agis? - Omnia recte. Quomodo habes?"

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks! I wasn't aware of this. Now if we can get the same thing in Ancient Greek...