# Is it "bene videtur" or "bonum videtur"? Adjective or adverb with verbs/copulae meaning "seem"

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, adjective, adverb

With verbs like "seem, appear", one sometimes uses an adverb to express how something appears ("she looked well"), at other times an adjective ("he seemed angry"). How did the Romans do it, specifically with the verb *videri*?

I was trying to say, "it seems good (to me)", in [this site's chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54125890#54125890), referring to an expression, and I was uncertain whether I should use a neuter adjective agreeing with the indeterminate subject or an adverb.

Comment: The "bene"/ "bonum" conflict was aired in Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4444/1982. The excellent adaption of Cicero's "quod male cecidit" = "what has turned out (fallen) badly" to give, "res bene cadent" = "things will turn out well" (by cnread) favours "bene". My attempt to use "bonum" in "omnia bona erunt" was assassinated by Unbrutal_Russian as "all the goods will be there"/ "all [neuter items] will be of good quality. This is one of my favourite Qs. Hope it helps!

Comment: @tony: Thanks for the link! It is indeed relevant, as it also has *esse*, another potential copula.

Comment: "Well", as in "she looked well", is an adjective ("she looked healthy"), not an adverb (unless you mean that she had a thorough look for something).

Comment: @fdb: I think that is a bit of a simplification.

Comment: @fdb: This was the quality of debate enjoyed on the earlier Q.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To express the (apparent) quality of something, only adjectives can be coupled with *videri*.

A few examples from Cicero, respectively *De Officiis* and *Brutus*:

> *Cum igitur id, quod utile videtur in amicitia, cum eo, quod honestum est, comparatur...*
> Thus, when what seems useful in friendship is compared with what is virtuous...

> [...] **qui eum sententiis, qui suffragiis adeptus est, is mihi et honestus et honoratus videtur.*[...]
> I consider honourable and respectable who achieves it [honour] through approval and election.

Answer (score 0):

According to Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict. "videtur" = "it seems good". Therefore, "videtur mihi" = "it seems good to me".

Also, Allen & Grrenough p.375(b): "The dative of the person who sees or thinks is regularly used after videor, seem:-"

"videtur mihi" = "it seems (or seems good) to me";

"videor mihi perspicere ipsius animum" (Fam. IV 13.5) =

"I seem (to myself) to see the soul of the man himself.)

This may not be exactly what you have asked for; but, perhaps, it obviates the "bene"/ "bonum" debate, referred to in Comments.

Comment: _videri_ means "it seems good" on its own only when used impersonally to introduce incidental propositions with _ut_ or _si_, and **certain** infinitive propositions (e.g. they must not contain themselves an impersonal verb).

Comment: @Vincenzo Oliva: The request was for, among other things, "it seems good (to me)". The A & G example of this did not offer any disqualifications of its use. Why do you think that is?

Comment: [Here](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dative-agent) is a link to that page. You can see that the line _videtur mihi_ is general, not taken from any particular context, unlike the others such as the one with _videor_ you mention. That's why it is translated with the parenthetical "or seems good": which one it is depends on the sentence it is in.

Comment: @Vincenzo Oliva: How would you say "It seems good to me"? I like your answer. It ends the "bene"/ "bonum" debate. Your counsel would've been welcome on the earlier Q. How are things in Calabria?

Comment: Res hic in Calabria satis bona videtur mihi.

Comment: Vincenzo Oliva: I don't know why I didn't pursue this at the time: "it seems good to me.", in isolation, no qualification. It would have to be a different word e.g. "mihi placet." = "It pleases (seems good to) me.". Do you agree?